# Accessing Method in dynamically created User Controls?

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

So I am still learning as I go and goggling a lot, but I just cannot seem to figure out how to access a method inside a dynamically created User Control.

I managed to get this working:

```
Control picture = new UserControl1();
picture.Visible = true;
picture.Name = "PIC1";
picture.Location = new Point(0, 0);
picture.Show();
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picture);

(UserControl1)picture).SetMSG("Test");
```

But I want to address each instance of the control by its name like this:

```
Control picture = new UserControl1();
picture.Visible = true;
picture.Name = "PIC1";
picture.Location = new Point(0, 0);
picture.Show();
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picture);

(UserControl1)PIC1).SetMSG("Test");
```

I think I may just be misunderstanding the entire concept?

Comment: Yeah, you pretty much are misunderstanding. Why would C# have any idea that `PIC1` is the name of some object?

Comment: Are you able to do this: `UserControl1 pic1 = new UserControl1();`? Do you have to use `Control picture`? Then you will be able to reference the control.

Comment: Well I wanted to have each one have a dynamic reference but simplified for the question. Something like int i = 1; i++; control picture + i = new UserControl();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a reference to your dynamically created controls in your view:

```
class MyView
{
    public void CreateControl(string name)
    {
        Control picture = new UserControl1();
        picture.Visible = true;
        picture.Name = name;
        picture.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        picture.Show();
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picture);

        this.controls.Add(name, picture);
    }

    public void SetMsg(string name, msg)
    {
        ((UserControl1)this.controls[name]).SetMSG(msg);
    }

    private Dictionary<string, Control> controls = new Dictionary<string, Control>();
}
```

Comment: This of course is extra work and will only benefit if you access the controls intensively in your view. Consider D Stanley's approach too since it is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I may just be misunderstanding the entire concept?

Yes you are.  You can't just use the name of a control like that.  You *could* do:

```
var PIC1 = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find("PIC1",false);
```

but you already *have* a reference to the control (`picture`) so I don't see the need to get a *different* reference.

Comment: I think my misunderstanding is in generating the controls to start with, Wouldn't I end up with multiple controls referenced as (picture) and so a change to one would change them all?

Comment: You can only have one `picture` variable, and a variable can only point to one thing - so no, you wouldn't be changing multiple items.  But I'd have to see more of your code to better understand how you're generating multiple controls.

Comment: So I would not be able to generate dynamically if I wanted to address them after they have generated. I would need a code block for picture1, 2 ,3 and so on or just not bother and do everything in designer as single objects

Comment: @user3464024 It's not really clear what you're _trying_ to do.  Yes, you can generate them dynamically, and either re-use `picture` or use different variable names.  But you can't dynamically reference a control by using it's `Name` as the variable.